# When scrolling an UITableView inside a UIScrollView and it bounces, the ScrollView also bounces

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I've got a UITableView in a UIView in a UIScrollView.

My problem is, when i scroll the tableview and it bounces, the scrollview bellow also bounces and i can see the background of the app which would be below the green UIScrollView.
Other than that, the tableview scrolls just fine inside the scrollview.

How can i fix this? 
Cheers

[image]

Comment: did you try disabling scrollview bounce ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable bouncing for what you do not want to bounce. (Also a good life motto.)

```
self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```